# Clear up some memory by removing processes shown by Top

Tags: users, background-process, top

I have an old user (bob) in my system. As per output of 'top' it seems that many processes are run by this user (command for most of them is'java'). As I have root access I deleted the user however still the processes keep running with user as '1000'. How do I stop these processes from running permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deleted the user and if that also deleted any cronjobs etc. that the user might have had, then rebooting the system should take care of killing their processes without restarting them when the system comes up again.

If rebooting is not an option, you may send a termination signal to all processes belonging to the user with UID 1000 using

```
sudu pkill -u 1000
```

You may see what processes would be affected by that command by first running

```
pgrep -u 1000
```

See also `man pkill`.

Answer (score 0):

First i will save do the current state of all process of the server to a file .

```
ps -wwfax -o uid=,pid=,ppid=,cmd=   > /root/list_of_process_as_today.txt
```

After i will focus on my bad user .

```
ps -wwfax -o uid=,pid=,ppid=,cmd=  | sed '/^ *1000  *\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*$/p;d'
```

A example of the output can be :

```
 1000  3096  3087      \_ sshd: em444@pts/0
 1000  3099  3096          \_ -bash
 1000  3543  3099              \_ ps -wwfax -o uid=,pid=,ppid=,cmd=
 1000  3544  3099              \_ sed /^ *1000  *\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*$/p;d
 1000 21628     1 SCREEN
 1000 21629 21628  \_ /bin/bash
```

Analysis of the list of process

my current shell is process 3099 .
you can see some child process , the command i ran *3543* , and one parent *3096*

You can see i have the process 21628 , his parent is process *1* , process *1* is parent of all process .

After i can use this command to kill all processes .

```
kill  $(/root/list_of_process_as_today.txt  | sed 's/^ *1000  *\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*$/\1/p;d')
```